# innerHTML doesn't set the value of SVG element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a running Angular 7 application and I want to update the value of text element based on dropdown selection.

eg: If the id of text element is 10, then update the value of text from 'hi' to 'hello'.

I am using setProperty innerHTML to update the value of text and it works fine in Chrome, but If I am trying the same behavior in IE text value is not getting updated.

```
<text id='10'>hi</text>


svgElement: SVGElement;
pathElement: HTMLElement;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

this.pathElement = svgElement.querySelector(`[id='10']`);
this.renderer.setProperty(this.pathElement, 'innerHTML', 'hello');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize the answer will be pretty simple. Actually, there is no need to use renderer, setProperty, innerHTML to set the value of SVG element. We can simply use ***textContent*** to set the value. It works for all browsers.

```
pathElement: SVGTextElement;

this.pathElement = svgElement.querySelector(`[id='10']`);
this.pathElement.textContent = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **DomSanitizer**

Try like this:

`import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'`

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

this.pathElement = svgElement.querySelector(`[id='10']`);
this.renderer.setProperty(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.pathElement), 'innerHTML', 'hello');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the DomSanitizer to setProperty, but it doesn't work in Chrome and IE. The text value is not getting updated. Is there any other solution..?

Comment: Can you reproduce and share this in stackbiltz